# printing time taken for merge sort

Tags: c, random, time, mergesort

i'm tryin' to print the time taken for a merge sort on an array of random numbers generated by the computer, whose size should be taken from the user during runtime, but it's givin' a segmentation fault. can anyone help correct my mistake?

```
part(int arr[],int min,int max)
{
 int mid;
 if(min<max)
 {
   mid=(min+max)/2;
   part(arr,min,mid);
   part(arr,mid+1,max);
   merge(arr,min,mid,max);
 }
}


merge(int arr[],int min,int mid,int max)
{
  int tmp[30];
  int i,j,k,m; 
  j=min;
  m=mid+1;
  for(i=min; j<=mid && m<=max ; i++)
  {
     if(arr[j]<=arr[m])
     {
         tmp[i]=arr[j];
         j++;
     }
     else
     {
         tmp[i]=arr[m];
         m++;
     }
  }
  if(j>mid)
  {
     for(k=m; k<=max; k++)
     {
         tmp[i]=arr[k];
         i++;
     }
  }
  else
  {
     for(k=j; k<=mid; k++)
     {
        tmp[i]=arr[k];
        i++;
     }
  }
  for(k=min; k<=max; k++)
     arr[k]=tmp[k];
}

main(){
int x, *b, i;
double t5;
printf("array size = \t");
scanf("%d", &x);
b = (int)malloc(x*sizeof(int));
srand(time(NULL));
for(i = 0; i<x; i++)    b[i] = rand();
time_t t1 = 0;
time_t t2 = 0;
t1 = time(NULL);
part(b, 0, (x-1));
t2 = time(NULL);
printf("time taken for merge sort = %f sec\n", (t1 - t2));
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Why are you casting b to an int, when it should be an int*?

Comment: @gregkow Better yet, remove the cast entirely.

Comment: i did declare b as a 'int *b', and i'm gettin' a segmentation fault

Comment: @user3248186 Where is the segmentation fault exactly.  What line, statement, etc?

Comment: during complilation it gave a warning @ the line where i used malloc, that the "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast" and nothin' else

Comment: @user3248186 When you call malloc, you should not cast it with (int)`. You shouldn't cast it at all. Just set `b=malloc(sizeof(int))`.

Comment: @gregkow removing the cast didn't matter as it's givin' a segmentation fault for array size greater than 35.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with the code here:

1. All relevant prototypes to system functions are missing, Fix this by including the necessary headers.
2. The prototype for `merge()` is missing, as needed by `part()`. Add it.
3. Functions not returning anything shall be typed as `void`. Declare them alike.
4. There is no need to cast the result of `malloc()`. And **if** it is done it should be done to the correct type: `int *` here not `int`!
5. `time_t` is an integer in most of the cases, so if it is don't use the conversion specifier for `double` when trying to print `time_t`, but the correct integer conversion specifier that is `d` for 32bit wide time_t or `ld` for 64bit wide  `time_t`. However to print difference of `time_t`s use `difftime()`, which actually **results** in a `double`.
6. Last not least the temporary buffer in `merge()` doesn't scale. Make it `max+1` elements wide.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void merge(int arr[], int min, int mid, int max);
void part(int arr[], int min, int max);

void part(int arr[], int min, int max)
{
  int mid;
  if (min < max)
  {
    mid = (min + max) / 2;
    part(arr, min, mid);
    part(arr, mid + 1, max);
    merge(arr, min, mid, max);
  }
}

void merge(int arr[], int min, int mid, int max)
{
  int tmp[max + 1];
  int i, j, k, m;
  j = min;
  m = mid + 1;
  for (i = min; j <= mid && m <= max; i++)
  {
    if (arr[j] <= arr[m])
    {
      tmp[i] = arr[j];
      j++;
    }
    else
    {
      tmp[i] = arr[m];
      m++;
    }
  }
  if (j > mid)
  {
    for (k = m; k <= max; k++)
    {
      tmp[i] = arr[k];
      i++;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    for (k = j; k <= mid; k++)
    {
      tmp[i] = arr[k];
      i++;
    }
  }
  for (k = min; k <= max; k++)
    arr[k] = tmp[k];
}

int main(void)
{
  int x, *b, i;

  printf("array size = \t");
  scanf("%d", &x);

  b = malloc(x * sizeof(int));

  srand(time(NULL ));
  for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
    b[i] = rand();

  time_t t1 = 0;
  time_t t2 = 0;

  t1 = time(NULL);
  part(b, 0, x - 1);
  t2 = time(NULL);

  printf("time taken for merge sort = %f sec\n", difftime(t2, t1));
}
```

Comment: Have not yet come across a platform where `time_t` was something other than an integer, but the C spec does not specify it must be an integer.  Assuming an integer, casting the difference is a reasonable approach as in `printf("time = %lld\n", (long long) (t2 - t1));` or `printf("time = %jd\n", (intmax_t) (t2 - t1));`

Comment: @chux: Yes you are right, `time_t` could even be `struct` or whatever ... - adjusted my wording.

Comment: Thorough diagnosis.  +1

Answer (score 1):

`time` uses a type called `time_t`.  To use it to find an elapsed time in seconds you must do something like this:

```
time_t time1, time2;
double seconds;

time(&time1);
...
time(&time2);

seconds = difftime(time2, time1);
```

Also, remove the cast from `malloc`.  `malloc` returns a `void` pointer which is implicitly cast to an `int` pointer for you:

```
b = malloc(x * sizeof(*b));
```

Comment: even when i removed the cast, and used difftime(t1, t2), it gave the same result - segmentation fault

Comment: @user3248186 Copy and paste the exact error into your question.

Comment: after i removed the cast before malloc, it's neither showing an error nor a warning, it's just givin' "segmentation fault" for array size greater than 35.

Comment: Recommend `difftime(time2, time1);`.

Comment: Sadly OP had it reversed too `(t1 - t2)`.